# jQuery counter question

Tags: jquery, jsf

I have a table and i want to count how many tr i hide.

The code:

```
<rich:jQuery query="ready(function() {
var i = 0;
jQuery('#inbox:_inboxTable_').find('span[title=isArchivedStatusPlusIncludeArchive]').each(function(i, o){
        if (jQuery(this).text() == 'true+false' ){
                i++;
                alert(i);
                jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut();
        }
    jQuery('#inbox').find('span[title=documentProccesedCountTitle]').html(i+' documents are beeing processed to be removed from the inbox');
});
})"/>
```

For a page with 10 tr, in my test 7 are hidden by this part of code but 'i' is 10 instead of 7 at the last step...

I just have no clue...why?
Does anyone see the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's a rich data table from jsf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i=10` because you are using it as an index of the function, try using `j` or something else:

```
jQuery('#inbox:_inboxTable_').find('span[title=isArchivedStatusPlusIncludeArchive]').each(function(j, o){
...
}
```

Also, instead of using `jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut();` you could use the [closest](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest) `jQuery(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();` (if the `tr` is your target).

Comment: I knew that was something small:) Thanks a lot.

Comment: And about the 2nd part of your answer: closest('tr') has harmfull behaviour in Firefox.

Comment: I've never had problems using `closest`, what problems are you experiencing or have you heard of? I'm curious.

Comment: here is a larger description of the problem i had: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1636945

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
$("#table_id tr:hidden").length
```

Comment: There are others tr hidden as well, so i cannot count on this solution.